# 64 bit operating system prerequisites?

Tags: 64-bit, installation, operating-systems, opensuse

Last night I want install Open Suse 11.3 64 bit edition to my new desktop computer. But my each attempt failed with general message "Error Occured". I think my computer may not be suitable for 64 bit system.

How can I learn suitability of my computer?

Comment: Find out what processor you have and Google it to see whether it supports 64-bit or not. :)

Comment: My processor is Intel Core i5-760. I guess it has a support for 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an operating system currently installed (and working) on the computer, you can use it to tell whether your processor is 64-bit or not. The method depends on which OS it is. On Linux, go to a command prompt and run the command `uname -m`, and if it prints `x86_64`, you have a 64-bit processor. Anything else means you don't. On Windows, I don't remember offhand but probably if you right-click My Computer and choose Properties you may find it in there somewhere.

If you don't have a functioning OS, you can probably get that information from the BIOS. Again, it depends on which BIOS you have, but usually there will be a notice that appears immediately when the computer starts up that says "Press F2 for Setup" or something like that (sometimes it's a different key, like Delete). If you hit that and poke around a bit in the menu that appears, you may see something that identifies your processor as 64-bit or 32-bit.

Also, I would agree with what nhinkle said about checking the integrity of the ISO image and of the burned CD.

Answer (score 1):

If the processor supports X86-64 or EM64T then it can run (what most people call) 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: True, but I suspect that won't be of much help to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is brand-new, the processor probably supports 64-bit operating systems. Intel has had x64 support from the Core 2 series on, and AMD has had it for ages, but do let us know what you have, or look it up. It's possible that something else might be causing your problem... did you download an ISO to install it? If so, it's possible your download got corrupted; you might want to verify the MD5 of the download, and when burning the disk, have your disk burning software verify the burn as well.

Comment: My processor is Intel Core i5-760.
I downloaded the ISO image and burned with Windows 7 internal CD/DVD burning tool.
Also I check the installation media at startup it report no errors found.

Comment: Tonight I am going to try with no-acpi support kernel. If it does not work. I going to try with Ubuntu 64 bit desktop edition.